# Почему при запуске Java random всегда один результат?

Tags: java

Почему каждый раз, когда запускаю сей код, один и тот же результат?

```
System.out.print((int)Math.random()*40+1);
```

Всегда выводит 1 - почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что ты приводишь к типу int число, которое меньше единицы

```
(int)Math.random()*40

Эта штука у тебя всегда ноль =)
```

То что тебе нужно вот так выглядит

```
        System.out.print((int)(Math.random()*40+1));
```

Comment: ТОчно! Спасибо!!

Comment: Бывает.. просто спать надо больше)