# Как поместить Random в цикл for что бы каждый раз когда он вызывался Random становилось новым числом?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

В итоге должен был получиться код который перебирает числа пока не найдет такое которое при перестановке цифр будет в 3 раза больше исходного

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class finali {
    static ArrayList<String> fig = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> fig1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    static int j, go1, go, a, b, c, d;
    static Random ran = new Random();

    public static void dat() {
        a = ran.nextInt(9);
        b = ran.nextInt(9);
        c = ran.nextInt(9);
        d = ran.nextInt(9);

        fig.add(String.valueOf(a));
        fig.add(String.valueOf(b));
        fig.add(String.valueOf(c));
        fig.add(String.valueOf(d));
        go = Integer.parseInt(fig.get(0) + fig.get(1) + fig.get(2) + fig.get(3));
        go1 = Integer.parseInt(fig.get(0) + fig.get(1) + fig.get(2) + fig.get(3));

        for (int fin = 1; go != go1 * 3; fin++) {
            Random ron = new Random();
            int r = ron.nextInt(4);
            Collections.swap(fig, 0, r);
            Collections.swap(fig, 1, r);
            Collections.swap(fig, 2, r);
            Collections.swap(fig, 3, r);
            go = Integer.parseInt(fig.get(0) + fig.get(1) + fig.get(2) + fig.get(3));
            System.out.println(go);

            if (fin == 1988) {
                j++;
                System.out.println("круг" + j);
                Thread ahka = new Thread();
                try {
                    ahka.sleep(10000);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        dat();
        for (; go != go1 * 3; ) {
            dat();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: в смысле? Какой дубликат?

Comment: У меня вопрос к постановке задачи в целом. Почему бы не перебирать числа от 1 до N, вместо перебора случайных чисел?

Comment: Так попроще и это пока что бета версия, мне главное чтобы она сработала , а потом доработаю до ума

Comment: Скорее так не проще, а сложнее. И еще у вас внутри цикла создание объекта `Random` каждый раз. Зачем?

Comment: а как рандом зациклить чтобы он каждый раз новое значение выдавал? Но я  Вас услышал попробую сделать через массив  с числами.

Comment: Спасибо за идею

Comment: и еще в `Java` принято именовать классы именами существительными с большой буквы. Постарайтесь соблюдать соглашения об именовании для Java. http://iprg.ru/index.php?topic=367.0

Comment: @ГеоргийЛапп массив тоже будет лишним. Просто в цикле увеличиваете число на 1 во время каждой итерации.

Comment: да что же это пошло такое. неделя вопросов об улучшении рандома:) формально, вопрос выше почти дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320633/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-rand-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5 только new radnom - это srand. nextInt - это rand

Comment: Я понял что Вы  хотите сделать просто перебор чисел но я хочу чтобы это происходило случайным образом. И все таки можно зациклить рандом или нет?

Comment: Что значит "зациклить" ?

Comment: Значит что каждый раз когда я запускаю метод dat  intы принимают другое значение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему при запуске Java random всегда один результат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170173/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-java-random-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: Так ваш код и так генерирует разные значения. Что именно с ним не так?

Comment: в том то и дело когда у одного числа он перебрал все значения и не нашел нужного он должен создать новое число и также начать искать

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы Random не возвращал одинаковые значения?

Comment: именно.Метод dat должен отработать и не найдя нужное значение запуститься опять с другими значениями

Comment: с Random'ом так сделать не получится. Используйте уже принятый вариант ответа и проходите все числа по порядку.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вместо того чтобы перебирать случайные числа до желаемого лучше всего надо просто получить рандом число с диапозоном.

```
ron.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

То есть тут вместо `min` в задаете число три раза больше исходного и вместо `max` максимальное число которое вы хотите.

И надо объявлять `Random ron = new Random();` за передалами цикла `for`, потому что при каждой итерации создается новый объект, а это лишние затраты. Вместо этого вам надо пользоваться уже обявленным объектом.